# bootstrap 4 dropdown child menu doesnt work on click

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this menu for show child dropdown menu using bootstrap 4:

```
<span class="menu-toggle">click</span>
<nav class="responsive-menu top-menu menu_wrap d-block d-lg-none d-xl-none open">
  <div class="menu_scroll_content">
    <ul class="menu_wrap">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-140 current_page_item menu-item-143 active"><a href="">home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item-has-children mega_menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60 mega_menu mega_menu_advanced dropdown">
        <a title="menu" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true"> menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-65 dropdown-submenu">
            <a title="child menu" href="#">child menu</a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-card menu-item-70">
                <a title="child menu 1" href="">child menu 1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-card menu-item-83">
                <a title="child menu 2" href="">child menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
//menu
$(document).on("click", ".menu-toggle", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").addClass("open-nav");
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("open");
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("show");
});
$(document).on("click", ".overlay,.close_nav", function() {
    $(".overlay").removeClass("show");
    $(".top-menu").removeClass("open");
    $("body").removeClass("open-nav");
});
$(document).on("click", ".responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children>a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("menu click");
    //$('.menu_wrap>li').removeClass('menu-show');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-show");
});
```

Now in action when click on `menu` show `child menu` and when click `child menu` show child child menu but when i need to close `menu` and click on `menu` menu not closest. how do fix this problem!?

Demo [Here](https://www.codeply.com/p/Zrc8JyFj6Q) (see on tablet or mobile preview)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This Script in after jquery script and before of your bootstrap js script Plugin

The link is:

[This add your script src="**https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js**"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js)

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi4LP.jpg)